# C# creating a table and inserting rows in to SQL Server 2008

Tags: c#, sql, .net, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Here's my connection string:

```
// Initialize a connection string    
string myConnectionString = 
   "Provider=SQLOLEDB;Data Source=hermes;Initial Catalog=qcvaluestest;
    Integrated Security=SSPI;";
```

How would I create a table in the database and insert rows into it?

Comment: Something similiar - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/204933/using-temporary-table-in-c

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Create table example:

```
CREATE TABLE MyTable
(
   Id  int IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED,
   Name        varchar(50) 
)
```

Insert records:

```
Insert INTO MyTable Values ("Abe")
```

You should think carefully before letting an application modify your DB structure though...

Alternatively you can use [SQL Server Management Objects](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162169.aspx).  Here is a good link that goes over using SSMO to create a table:

http://www.davidhayden.com/blog/dave/archive/2006/01/27/2775.aspx

**UPDATE**
Your C# would look like this:

```
string queryString = 
    @"
CREATE TABLE MyTable
(
   Id  int IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED,
   Name        varchar(50) 
)";

using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(
           myConnectionString ))
{
    SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(
        queryString, connection);
    connection.Open();
    command.ExecuteNonReader();
    command.CommandText = @"Insert INTO MyTable Values ('Abe')";
    command.ExecuteNonReader();
}
```

Comment: Do you mean that you want to execute the SQL using C#?